# How can I prevent "not-yet-approved" Admins from accessing Admin functions in my web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So that multiple people can be an administrator to a business page, we've created a model called administration where people can apply to be an admin of a business and thus the status of "0" is "pending" and "1" is accepted.

How can I prevent users from editing a page where their status for i is still "0" (pending).

```
class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :business_id, :user_id, :status
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :business
  scope :pending, where('status = ?',0).order("updated_at desc")


  def self.new_by_user_business( user, business)
    admin = self.new
    admin.business_id = business.id
    admin.user_id = user.id
    admin.status = 0
    admin.save!

  end
end
```

Here is the current "edit page"

```
<h1>Editing business</h1>
<%= render 'form1' %>
```

Here is the business controller.

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @businesses = Business.all
    respond_with(@businesses)
  end

  def show
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != business_path(@business)
        redirect_to @business, status: :moved_permanently
    end

  end

  def new

    @business = Business.new
    3.times { @business.assets.build }
    respond_with(@business)
  end

  def edit

    @business = get_business(params[:id])
    @avatar = @business.assets.count
    @avatar = 3-@avatar
    @avatar.times {@business.assets.build}
  end

  def create
    @business = Business.new(params[:business])
    if @business.save
      redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully created.'
    else
      3.times { @business.assets.build }
      render 'new'
    end
end

  def update
    @business = get_business(params[:id])
    if @business.update_attributes(params[:business])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Business."
    end
    @avatar = @business.assets.count
    @avatar = 3-@avatar
    @avatar.times {@business.assets.build}
    respond_with(@business)
  end

  def destroy
    @business = get_business(params[:id])
    @business.destroy
    respond_with(@business)
  end

  def my_business
    @business = Business.all
  end

  def business_tickets
    @user = current_user
    @business = get_business(params[:id])
    @tickets  = @business.tickets
    @business_inbox = TicketReply.where(:email => @business.callred_email)
  end

  def your_business
    @user = current_user
    @business = get_business(params[:id])
      if @business.users.map(&:id).include? current_user.id
        redirect_to my_business_businesses_path, notice: 'You are already an administator of this business.'
      else
        @admin = Administration.new_by_user_business( @user, @business)

          BusinessMailer.delay(queue: "is_your_business", priority: 20, run_at: 5.minutes.from_now).is_your_business(@user,@business)
          redirect_to @business, notice: 'Thank you for claiming your business, and we will be in touch with you shortly.'

      end
  end

  def view_message
  #  @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @reply = @ticket.ticket_replies
  end

  private
  def get_business(business_id)
    @business = Business.find(business_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `before_filter` to check the status. You will have to change some of the logic but this is the idea

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :restrict_access, :only => [:edit, :update]

  private
  def restrict_access
    @business = get_business(params[:id])
    redirect to root_path, :notice => "Not Authorized" unless current_user.status == 1
  end
end
```

Comment: How would you edit it so it checks the status?  u.status == 1

Comment: @AndrewCharlesPotterKelley: Modified my answer. Not sure if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks @Vimsha - Unfortunately, I get a "undefined method `status'" for that.